# How to fix "QML TableViewColumn: Accessible must be attached to an Item"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml, qtreeview

I have an application written with PyQt5 and QML. Part of the application should be a QML TreeView. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678626/pyqt5-qml-treeview-example) I was able to craft a minimal example of how a TreeView should be written between PyQt5 and QML, but every time I put a "TableViewColumn" in my QML file I get this error:

```
QML TableViewColumn: Accessible must be attached to an Item
```

This error shows up exactly once for each TableViewColumn I add in my code. Also, strangely, if I add a "FileDialog" in my QML file, I get this error several more times.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQuick

class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.itemData = data["data"]
        self.childItems = []

        for child in data["children"]:
            self.childItems.append(TreeItem(child, self))

    def child(self, row):
        return self.childItems[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childItems)

    def columnCount(self):
        return len(self.itemData)

    def data(self, column):
        try:
            return self.itemData[column]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentItem

    def row(self):
        if self.parentItem:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)
        return 0


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rootItem = TreeItem(data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            return parent.internalPointer().columnCount()
        else:
            return self.rootItem.columnCount()

    def roleNames(self):
        d = dict()
        for i in range(self.rootItem.columnCount()):
            d[QtCore.Qt.UserRole + i] = self.rootItem.data(i).encode()
        return d

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.data(index.column())
        elif role >= QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item.data(role - QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.rootItem.data(section)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        childItem = parentItem.child(row)
        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        childItem = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = childItem.parent()

        if parentItem == self.rootItem:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        return parentItem.childCount()

def main():
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtQuick.QQuickView(resizeMode=QtQuick.QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)

    data = {"data": ("Name", "Checked"), "children" : [
        { "data" : ("a", False), "children" : [
            { "data" : ("test1", False), "children" : []},
            { "data" : ("test2", False), "children" : []},
            { "data" : ("test3", False), "children" : []},
        ] },
        { "data" : ("b", False), "children" : [] },
        { "data" : ("c", False), "children" : [] },
    ]}

    can_signal_model = TreeModel(data)
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("modelCan", can_signal_model)
    qml_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "test.qml")
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath(qml_file)))

    if view.status() == QtQuick.QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)

    view.show()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the "test.qml":

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 480
    height: 640

    TreeView {
        id: treeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 6
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        model: modelCan

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "Name"
            resizable: true
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Checked"
            role: "Checked"
            resizable: true
        }
    }

    // Optional
    /*
    FileDialog {
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: What version of pyqt5 do you use? I use PyQt5 5.15.2 and I don't see that problem

Comment: @eyllanesc I was on 5.15.1. I tried updating to 5.15.2 and that fixed it, thank you!